# Django : While refreshing the content is posting again [duplicate content]

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I created an app to post comments from users but while refreshing the page the last posted content is posting again as duplicate..

models.py

```
class chat_content(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        ct_cnt = chat_content.objects.all()
        return render(request,'discussion/discussion_board.html',{'form':cont,'cnt':ct_cnt})
    else:
        form = cont(data=request.POST)
        form.save(commit=True)
        frm = cont()
        ct_cnt = chat_content.objects.all()
        print(ct_cnt)
        return render(request,'discussion/discussion_board.html',{'form':cont,'cnt':ct_cnt})
```

forms.py

```
class cont(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = chat_content
        fields = ('content',)
```

.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
Welcome to the public discussion
{% for c in cnt %}
<div>
    {{ c }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
<form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

How can i avoid duplicates when refreshing ??

for example

the last comment is : "welcome all"

while refreshing the page the content updated as duplicate and showing as : "welcome all" "welcome all"

where i can correct this duplicates ?? 
Is there any easy way to use ajax in this code ??

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

Instead of showing HTML page you need to redirect to this page after posting:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

form = cont(data=request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    return redirect(home)
```

In this case user will refresh GET page so content will not duplicate.

Comment: thanks for good explanations.. but still it showing error like "Reverse for 'discussion.views.home' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []"

Comment: What is the name of this view in `urls.py`?  Pass this name to `redirect` function instead of `home`.